# Grab a frame from video on android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to grab a frame from video (currently being recorded) on android 2.1
For this I am having 2 options:

1. Record a video and grab the frame from the video.
2. Use `Camera.onPreviewFrame' to take the frame.

I am using option no. 2 right now. But the size of images are larger enough. I want it to be small (around 10k to 25k). Is there any way to decompress the image on android?

For the option 1, I am thinking to record a video on sdcard,read it and extract the frames. Is it possible to do that on android 2.1?

Which one will be the better option (option 1 or option 2) for grabbing the frame?

What other things i will need in option 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Up Camera Parameters Will Reduce the Size of Preview Frames...

```
Camera.Parameters parameters;  
parameters = camera.getParameters();  
parameters.setPreviewSize(176,144);  
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: video size should be of 320X240